# Postgres COPY command to tail a file?

Tags: postgresql

I want to use to copy command to copy data into postgres; while there other processes are simultaneously writing into the CSV file.

Is something like this possible? Take the stdout from tail and pipe into the stdin of postgres.

```
COPY targetTable ( column1, column2 )
    FROM `tail -f 'path/to/data.csv'`
    WITH CSV
```

Comment: The psql version `\copy` might work. It at least supports reading from stdin and from pstdin. Try `man psql` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming PostgreSQL 9.3 or better, there's the possibility of copying from a program output with:

```
COPY FROM PROGRAM 'command'
```

From [the doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> PROGRAM
>
> A command to execute. In COPY FROM, the input is read from standard
>   output of the command, and in COPY TO, the output is written to the
>   standard input of the command.

This may be what you need except for the fact that `tail -f` being a never-ending command by design, it's not obvious how you plan for the COPY to ever finish. Presumably you'd need to replace `tail -f` by a more elaborate script with some exit condition.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the command is executed in the back end in this case, by the postgres user, not the user running psql or whatever client, so permissions might be an issue.

Comment: That is a good point. I would replace tail -f with some other script that exits. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

you can also do COPY  FROM STDIN;
example:

```
tail -f datafile.csv | psql -tc "COPY table from STDIN" database
```

Comment: I +1ed originally, but Daniel Vérité makes a good point: `tail -f` never finishes!

Comment: Would that actually work, even  ignoring the issue of how it would ever end? I would have thought you would have to use \copy from pstdin. STDIN in the SQL command means 'from the client connection' not necessarily the stdin of the client itself.

Comment: Came here looking for using `tail` for only the last record in a `.sql` file.  `tail -n 1 datafile.sql | psql database -tc "\COPY table FROM STDIN"`

Comment: `tail -f` never ends